# Getting annotation values from @XMLElement in a java class

Tags: java, annotations, jaxb, xmlelement

I am trying to get the @XMLElement annotations from a java class that I have, basically trying to make a map of variables where the annotation is required: true. However it prints out nothing.

I have a java class that has the following snippet:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
  "subjectCode",
   "version",
   "messageTitle",
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "CreateMessageRequest", namespace = "mynamespaceblahblah")
public class CreateMessageRequest
  extends AbstractRequest
  implements Serializable
{

private final static long serialVersionUID = 10007L;
@XmlElement(namespace = "mynamespaceblahblah", required = true)
protected String subjectCode;
@XmlElement(namespace = "mynamespaceblahblah")
protected String version;
@XmlElement(namespace = "mynamespaceblahblah", required = true)
protected String messageTitle;


//Getters and setters
}
```

I tried this:

```
 public HashMap<String, String> getRequired(Class<?> c) {

HashMap<String, String> fieldMap = new HashMap<>();

Annotation[] annotations = c.getAnnotations();
for (int i = 0; i < annotations.length; i++) {

  Annotation annotation = annotations[i];
  if (annotation instanceof XmlElement) {
    XmlElement theElement = (XmlElement) annotation;
    String name = ((XmlElement) annotation).name();

    if (theElement.required()) {
      fieldMap.put(name, "true");
    } else {
      fieldMap.put(name, "false");
    }
  }
}
return fieldMap;
}
```

But when I use my method with:

```
SchemaBuilder s = new SchemaBuilder();
System.out.println("Required Methods of class:");

HashMap<String, String> fieldMap = s.getRequired(CreateMessageRequest.class);

for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : fieldMap.entrySet()) {
  System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue());
}
```

It prints out

```
Required Methods of class:
```

Any advice to what I'm doing wrong? I've considered that because its protected I cant access it (I cannot change the annotated class unfortunately) but I am not sure that is the problem.

Comment: Note that `c.getAnnotations()` only gets the annotations that are on the class itself, not the annotations on the methods in the class. You'll need to find the methods using reflection, and then get the annotations on each of the methods that were found.

Comment: Interesting, I will give it a shot

Comment: @Jesper However, since we're looking for *field* annotations here, finding the *methods* is of no use to us, so maybe finding fields would be more useful. --- Then again, those annotations can also be placed on getter/setter methods, so perhaps finding both would be even better. Just remember to add logic to derive element name from method name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to look at the individual fields as per the suggestions :)

In order to help future googlers:

```
public HashMap<String, String> getRequired(Class<?> c) {

HashMap<String, String> fieldMap = new HashMap<>();

Field[] fields = c.getDeclaredFields();
for (Field f : fields) {

  Annotation[] annotations = f.getAnnotationsByType(XmlElement.class);
  for (int i = 0; i < annotations.length; i++) {
    Annotation annotation = annotations[i];

    if (annotation instanceof XmlElement) {
      XmlElement theElement = (XmlElement) annotation;
      String name = f.getName();
      if (theElement.required()) {
        fieldMap.put(name, "true");
      } else {
        fieldMap.put(name, "false");
      }
    }
  }
}
return fieldMap;
}
```